# Given the points $A,B,C,D$ in a straight line $m$ and $A,E,F,G$ in a straight line $n$, how many triangles can be formed with these points?

Tags: combinatorics

Given the points $A,B,C,D$ in a line $m$ and $A,E,F,G$ in a straight line $n$, how many triangles can be formed with these points?

I've done the following:

> [image]

I've used the following heuristic: Chose one point on $m$, then another point on $m$ which is different of the previous chosen point. This yields $4*3$, now choose a new point on $n$, this gives me $4*3*3=36$, now choose one point on $n$ and another point on $n$ different of the last point chosen and different of $A$. This gives me $3*2*3=12$ and hence $36+12=48$.

I've also tried to do it in the following way:

$${\text{#points in m} \choose 2}*\text{#points in n (w/o A)}+ {\text{#points in n (w/o A)} \choose 2}*\text{#points in m (w/o A)}$$

Then:

$${4 \choose 2}*3 + {3 \choose 2}*3=27$$

But none of them is right. I may be missing some triangles but I cant see which ones are these.

Comment: I found 18 triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** First let us count the triangles that have $A$ as a vertex. We need to choose a point other than $A$ on each line.

Next we count the triangles that don't have $A$ as a vertex. We pick $2$ points other than $A$ on one line, and $1$ on the other, or the other way around.

Comment: Choosing $A$, I'd have 3 options in $m$ and $3$ options in $n$, so $1*3*3=9$. Now choosing two points in $m$ and one in $n$, I'll have ${3 \choose 2}*3=9$. Now choosing two points in $n$ and one in $m$, I'd have ${3 \choose 2}*3=9$. Hence *9+9+9=27*. But this answer is wrong. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the answer is $42$.

Comment: How can it be 42?

Comment: If we have $4$ points other than $A$ on one line, and $3$ on the other, the method gives $12+18+12=42$. So maybe one point was left off the problem as stated? It would be $42$ with $ABCD$, $AEFGH$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh, sorry. It had one more point, I didn't see it.

Comment: Good, then my comment also answers that one.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example, 
If you choose BEGC: one line from BE, one from GC, and one from EG--> you have one more triangle. Do the same  for the rest and I think you may get the result.

Comment: Didn't read all the comments, but I think your question is missing information. It didn't ask the apexes had to be the points!